# ECLIPSE RCP - lightweight decorator with objectState enablement

Tags: eclipse, decorator, rcp

How use this functionality that `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` provides? Lets say I have some object in `TreeViewer` and want to enable decorator only when object has "dirty" property set to `true`? Do I have to build some `Decorator` implementation or only use of `objectState` in `plugin.xml` extension will fulfill my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A brilliant colleague of mine" section in this post may be helpful
[In Eclipse RCP, how do I disable a save toolbar button according to the "dirty" property in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650775/in-eclipse-rcp-how-do-i-disable-a-save-toolbar-button-according-to-the-dirty)

Answer (score 1):

This article may prove useful:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html

Also the extension point documentation:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_decorators.html

And the wiki:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_label_decorator_declaratively%3F

And the platform help:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_decorators.htm